# Code for guessing game won't print anything after I enter my number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a guessing game with python but my code won't seem to work. I am just getting into python so I am not the best. Here is my code.

```
print "Hello"
print "You have found me, haven't you?"
print "Well, since you did all the work to find me..."
print "I will let you have my diamond and gold infused microwave!"
print "But there is a twist"
print "You have to guess my favorite number! You only have one try!"
print "It is a number from 1 to 5"

guess=raw_input("What is my number?")

import random

for x in range(1):
  print random.randint(1,5)

correct=random.randint

def correct_number(correct):
    if correct==guess:
        print "Dang! You got it!"
    elif correct > guess:
        print "Wrong! Too low!"
    elif correct < guess:
        print "Wrong! Too High!"
```

I need it to say "Dang it! You won!" if you get it right, "Wrong! Too high!" if your guess is too high, and "Wrong! Too low!" if your guess is too low.

Comment: make sure to format your code correctly so it can be read easily: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: *"my code won't seem to work"* - that's a meaningless description. What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? If so, what is your error? Are you asking why it isn't behaving like you expect?

Comment: @yuvi I'm sure he's getting a `TypeError: unorderable types: function() > int()`, but I agree that the question is too vague

Comment: you also never call the function `correct_number`. Try adding a line that says `correct_number(correct)` at the end.

Comment: @AdamSmith he might also get an error for mixing tabs and spaces. For all I know he's running it from Sublime Text and gets an EOF error because it doens't handle `raw_input`.In any way, *"doesn't work"* is a terrible description

Comment: When I run it, everything goes fine. I type in my guess and hit enter. The random number the computer chooses gets printed and nothing else happens. No errors. Nothing.

Comment: @PotatoBob ah that's because as ari mentioned: you never run the function you define. If you DID run that function, you'd see that it gives a `TypeError` because of the `correct = random.randint` thing our answers pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

```
correct=random.randint
```

This sets `correct` to be the function *that produces* a random number, not a random number itself.

There's a number of things wrong or "weird" about the code, but this is what's causing your error. You should instead CALL the function

```
correct = random.randint(1,5)
```

And speaking of calling functions, you never call your `correct_number` function either. You should probably do something like:

```
guess = raw_input("what is my number? ")
correct = random.randint(1,5)

def correct_number():
    if guess == correct:
        # yay
    if guess < correct:
        # too low
    if guess > correct:
        # too high

correct_number()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
correct=random.randint
```

`random.randint` is a function.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint
<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x7ffa7b072220>>
```

So your assigning a function to variable `correct`, not the *result* of the function, which is what you want. If you change it to the following it should work.

```
correct=random.randint(1, 5)
```